# How do I put on gas and setup the blockchain?

Tags: wallets

I downloaded ethereum wallet nad bought some coins. They dont appear. It says that to view transactions, I have to make a contract. When I try to do that it says its exceeding gas limit. Also it says it's waiting for Blocks. Can't find anywhere on how to set up a the Block. Please help. I'm New.

Comment: Welcome. It might help someone help you out to provide a little more detail. You can include the version of the wallet you're using, Windows/Mac/Phone, etc, how long it's been running and what says you need to make a contract. Any detail that might help someone recognize what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

You say you bought some coins but they didn't show up. The most likely cause of this is because your node was not yet synced. You then misread the message on Mist that says to "view" transactions you have to make a contract. You're mistaking viewing your balance and viewing your transactions. If you've added the correct address to watch in Mist, then if--and only if--the node is synced will you see your balance. You don't have to see your transactions to see your balance.

When it says "waiting for blocks" I think that means that your node is not synced.

Syncing takes a very long time, especially on computers with slower hard drives. My guess is that your sync is slowing down significantly near block 2390000 or so. This is the DDOS attack. The only thing you can do is wait until it syncs.

You can always look at that same address on http://etherscan.io or some other blockchain scraper. You should see your balance there (and the transactions).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to watch the contract and token to be able to see them, but you'll need to add some more info like Rob said. Specifically, what tokens did you buy?

Also do you see yourself connecting to peers, or is 'blocks left' not decreasing.

Comment: OP said coins not tokens. I took that to mean ETH. If OP bought tokens they would have to add a Token Watch. There should be instructions with the token sale on how to do that.